# SharePoint 2010 Crawls successfully, but Internal Server Error appears when searching

Tags: 2010, search, error, sharepoint-server, server

I have an intranet built on SP 2010. Everything works except the Search feature (not using FAST Search).

My content source is Local SharePoint Sites, crawls return 40k+ results.

However, when I search, I always get the following error:

> Error
>   Internal server error exception:
>   Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation.
>   Correlation ID: 7ef88eb0-47d5-4e0f-b5cf-177ebca4a6df
>   Date and Time: 6/25/2014 3:40:13 PM

This seems to be very ambiguous, and I've seen dozens of postings with similar search problems, but no consistent remedy for the situation.

Answer (score 1):

Their are many reasons for this issue. You have to check the ULS logs for against that correlation id to get more info.if you have powershell access run the below command on one of the server to get complete trace.

```
Merge-SPLogFile -correlation "7ef88eb0-47d5-4e0f-b5cf-177ebca4a6df" -Path "C:\Error.log" -StartTime "06/25/2014 03:35" - EndTime "06/25/2014 03:42"
```

share the logs.

Possible issues for the error are:

- Reboot your server(s). Ensure that your search services have started.
- Ensure you dont have any issues with your search databases. Eg. Out
  of disk space, SQL Alias not present on all SharePoint servers.
- You will have to install the following hotfix
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=166231 For Windows Server 2008
  R2, Hotfix for.NET Framework 3.5 SP1 that provides a method to
  support the token authentication without transport security or
  message encryption in WCF
  (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=166231).
- may be this fix http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2908052